# Notation for "all integers less than $n$"

Tags: notation

Is there a short mathematical notation for *all integers less than $n$* where $n$ itself is some integer? The only thing that comes to mind is
$$\mathbb{Z} \cap (-\infty, n),$$
But this is pretty ugly and involves reals. Is there a better way to do this symbolically, or should I just describe such set with words?

Comment: $$\Bbb Z_{<n}$$

Answer (score 7, accepted):

$ \mathbb{Z}^{< n} $ is sometimes used (I personally like the notation $ \mathbb{Z}_{< n} $ more as I like to reserve the right upper corner for powers, but I don't think I have seen others use it). The $< n$ in the top right can look a little bit weird, because there is no variable on the left side.

Another option is $ k \in \mathbb{Z} $, with $ k < n$. It is also pretty common to just write "for all integers less than $n$" as you did. I think these two options are the most commonly used.

Also, you could write 'for $k \in \{ j \in \mathbb{Z} : j < n \}$', but I don't think many authors would do so. I'm sure there are some other possibilities, but these are the most common ones I can think of.

Comment: I didn't know about the subscript notation, that's pretty neat. Thanks.

Comment: I don't know how common its use is, though. I just saw it used in the syllabus for one course. I'm hoping some other people can shine some more light on this.

Answer (score 4):

I would use

$$ \{ x \in \mathbb Z \mid x < n \} . $$

Answer (score 3):

I have seen the notation $[k<n]$ used several times, first in a combinatorics class when I was an undergrad, and then in another place. By induction, it should hold for all authors.

Comment: I would think this is the Iverson bracket, denoting $1$ is $k<n$ and $0$ otherwise. As a function of $k\in\Bbb Z$ that would be the _characteristic function_ of the set in the question, but noting in the notation you wrote says that $k$ is variable, or that it ranges over $\Bbb Z$.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe (almost surely) it's not so standard, but sometimes I saw the use of $\bar{n} $ to indicate the set of natural numbers less or equal to $ n $. I suppose there is an analogue notation for integers.

For references: I found this notation in several random pdfs downloaded from Internet, not "ufficial" books (at least book i know). I addee this answer because I found the notation suitable for someone who doesn't want to write "long" formulas :)